# Could a helcopteri fly with 1 propeller?

Tags: aerodynamics

If a helicopter had 2 stacked rotors with 1 propeller each, could it theoretically fly?

Comment: Helicopters don't have propellers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could, but the stress on the axle of the rotor would be too high due to the non-uniform distribution of masses (similar to the gif below). Such a helicopter would be extremely uncomfortable to ride in, due to the resulting vibrations. Moreover, the life of such a rotor would be much shorter than the symmetric two-leafed rotor, so even if you manage to make one, you wouldn't want to fly in one.

[image]